# How to delete push API from Intel XDK?

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, intel-xdk

How to delete push API from Intel XDK? Im trying to submit iOS app to iTunes Connect, But Apple always send me Alert

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "***". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

So, Im not using any API with push notification, it could be default Intel XDK Cordova API, how to fix this alert or how to delete API?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be included by default, so you may want to look at the project page and make sure that "Notification" is not checked.  This is under Plugins->"Featured and Custom plugins"->"Intel XDK Plugins", near the bottom, so you'll need to scroll down on the right to see it.